# Unable to open directories placed in desktop [Ubuntu 18.04.1]

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

Since I have upgraded my system from **Ubuntu 18.04** to **18.04.1**, I am facing a weird problem.

I am unable to open any directory placed on the desktop by double-clicking on it. However, when I Right-Click on the folder icon and select **Nautilus** it opens up. I can even access them by opening **Nautilus** from the menu. I don't know why is this happening. Is this some bug of 18.04.1? Should I revert back to 18.04?.

**Update**

I tried following things which didn't worked

1. Tried reinstalling `gnome-shell`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
   ```
2. Tried reinstalling `nautilus`

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge nautilus
   sudo apt-get install nautilus
   ```
3. Checked the permission of folders in desktop, they are ok
4. Checked mouse setting in the Settings menu, they are ok

I also tried installing Ubuntu 18.04.1 in a virtual box with same iso file, what I found is that in VM newly installed Ubuntu works fine I can open the folder by double-clicking on them. Hence I believe I might have installed some drivers along the way which are creating a problem.